# Returning values after last NA in a vector

Tags: r

Returning values after last NA in a vector

I can remove all NA values from a vector

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,NA,7,8,9,10,11,12)
v2 <- na.omit(v1)
v2
```

but how do I return a vector with values only after the last NA

```
c( 7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could detect the last `NA` with `which` and add 1 to get the index past the last `NA` and index until the `length(v1)`:

```
 v1[(max(which(is.na(v1)))+1):length(v1)]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Fails in limit case `v1[13] <- NA`.

Comment: By far the fastest

Comment: What do you mean fail? It returns NA, and I assume thats the correct response, apart from returning 2 NA's, I guess would be a problem in some niche applications @RuiBarradas

Comment: @HectorHaffenden The question ask for the vector elements "*after* the last `NA`". WHen the last element is `NA`, it should return nothing, meaning, `NULL`.

Comment: Think I have misunderstood, what would you expect the output to be if the vector is `c(1,2,3,NA)` @RuiBarradas

Comment: @HectorHaffenden I would expect either `NULL` or `numeric(0)` as in the [answer by @d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363443/returning-values-after-last-na-in-a-vector/55363641#55363641).

Answer (score 2):

You could detect the last `NA` with `which`

```
v1[(tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1) + 1):length(v1)]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

However, the most general - as *@MrFlick* pointed out - seems to be this:

```
tail(v1, -tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1))
# [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

which also handles the following case correctly:

```
v1[13] <- NA
tail(v1, -tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1))
# numeric(0)
```

To get the null `NA` case, too,

```
v1 <- 1:13
```

we can do

```
if (any(is.na(v1))) tail(v1, -tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1)) else v1
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

***Data***

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, NA, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

Comment: Or if you want to return the values of `v1` when the vector does not contain consecutive indices (like `v1 <- c(5,NA,20,30)`, something like `tail(v1, -tail(which(is.na(v1)),1))` should work more generally

Comment: `13` is not in `v1`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for the pointer, there was something missing.

Comment: @MrFlick Clever, this nesting, noted!

Comment: @MrFlick We'll fail if there's no `NA` at all, though; `v1 <- 1:13`.

Answer (score 2):

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,NA,7,8,9,10,11,12)
v1[seq_along(v1) > max(0, tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1))]
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

v1 = 1:5
v1[seq_along(v1) > max(0, tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1))]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

v1 = c(1:5, NA)
v1[seq_along(v1) > max(0, tail(which(is.na(v1)), 1))]
#integer(0)
```

Comment: But a bit slow, due to `tail`. (Mine is an order of magnitude faster, tested with `microbenchmark`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an alternative solution that does not use indices and only vectorised operations:

```r
after_last_na = as.logical(rev(cumprod(rev(! is.na(v1)))))
v1[after_last_na]
```

The idea is to use `cumprod` to fill the non-`NA` fields from the last to the end. It’s not a terribly useful solution in its own right (I urge you to use the more obvious, index range based solution from other answers) but it shows some interesting techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want.

```
i <- which(is.na(v1))
if(i[length(i)] < length(v1)){
  v1[(i[length(i)] + 1):length(v1)]
}else{
  NULL
}
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12
```